# Fetch bots own message

Tags: discord.js

Trying to make a ping command, want to edit the "Pinging..." command with a embed, but do not know how i  can get the info for the "Pinging..." command

Here's my code:

```
        }else if(command === "ping"){
            
            const msg = message.channel.send('Pinging...');//.then(fetch);
            const msginfo = Discord.TextChannel.message.fetch(msg);
            console.log(msginfo);
            
            const embedPing = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0xC1CCDE)
            .setTitle('Pong!')
            .setDescription(`Bot Latency is **${Math.floor(msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp)} ms** \nAPI Latency is **${Math.round(client.ws.ping)} ms**`);
            
            setTimeout(() =>  message.channel.send(embedPing), 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `await` to the `message.channel.send` and then edit the message with the latency information

```js
const msg = await message.channel.send('Pinging...');

msg.edit(`Bot Latency is **${Math.floor(msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp)} ms** \nAPI Latency is **${Math.round(client.ws.ping)} ms**`);
```